# Adobe Assets - .psd - something similar?

Tags: css, adobe, inspect, psd

I always used Adobe Assets for inspect psd - now I found, it's not possible to use this anymore. Do you know about something similar (except Photoshop)?

Comment: If you have the Adobe cloud services you can use - http://www.adobe.com/creativecloud/extract.html

Comment: I think it's what I am talking about :) It's not working anymore - they canceled this function..

Comment: Annie Try https://editor.redaktor.io/, it's free check here for a tutorial:  https://medium.com/@redaktorio/psd-to-html-editor-in-your-browser-b3116af6af1f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at following blog post talking about 'Avocode', it's not a free product. But simular in feature.

[Link](https://creativemarket.com/blog/2014/08/29/from-psd-to-css-avocode-vs-creative-cloud-extract)

[Read more about Adobe Extract](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/adobe-extract-free-code-extraction-from-psd-files-in-the-cloud--cms-21938)

Comment: Yes, I know that - maybe I'll choose this even if it's not free :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Extract for Brackets got dis-continued. It's better to try something free e.g. https://editor.redaktor.io/

You can extract images, fonts, text, css, etc. Do PSD to HTML development right in your browser.

They have posted a video and a small tutorial here:
https://medium.com/@redaktorio/psd-to-html-editor-in-your-browser-b3116af6af1f